# Prepared statement, binding with wrong data doesn't throw an error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Why is it that when binding to a parameter that is of an invalid type, I don't get an error? For instance:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SCHEMA);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update app_site_group set name_eng=?, name_fra=? where app_site_group_id=?");

$one = "one";
$two = "two";
$three = "a";
$stmt->bind_param('ssi',$one,$two,$three);

$stmt->execute();
```

The third parameter is passed as a string when an integer was expected. It doesn't throw an error (other than having 0 rows affected).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `i` you supply as an integer is the type MySQLi will pass the value into the query as. However, the API itself doesn't actually care whether the value it gets a string or an integer. PHP/MySQLi will be sure to *cast* the string to an integer when passing it to the RDBMS.

Numeric-looking strings will therefore be cast to their integer equivalent.  For non-numeric strings like your `'a'`, the result will be the integer `0`, which may or may not match rows in your data.

```
echo (int)'a';
// 0
```

So in your case the query that was executed looked like

```
update app_site_group set name_eng = 'one', name_fra = 'two'  where app_site_group_id = 0
```

If you had rows where `app_site_group_id = 0`, then those would have been matched.  So in addition to using prepared statements, it is important to always *validate* the contents of the parameters so you are sure they contain sane values.